# SoapUI and Groovy: How to call a compiled jar file as if from the command line?

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am writing a test that requires me to execute a java file at one point.  The Java file is already compiled and I do not have access to the source code or documentation.

I know if I open up a command prompt and execute the file via typing: "java -jar someFile.jar - someOptions" then the step I need done is executed properly.

I have tried the groovy script

```
def output = "java -jar someFile.jar - someOptions".execute().text
log.info output
```

However this simply gives me an empty log entry.

I am not sure if the issue is that the java takes some time to execute (it involves server calls) and thus the output has not been written to the string before I try to log the output.

I am also not sure if the script can see the .jar file.  I have placed it in my \bin\ext folder.  However I also need this test to be OS agnostic so I'm really hesitant to hard code paths in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def command = "java -jar someFile.jar - someOptions"
def process = command.execute()
process.waitFor()

def output = process.in.text
log.info ouput
```

Use waitFor() since you want the process to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can point SoapUI at the location where the jar file is being held and it will compile it on the start up of the test. This should then let you call the already compiled file from a groovy step